# <Closed> how I can access the value of the properties in the object stored in objects

Tags: c#, object

I have class Role:

```
 class Role
    {
        public Role(Type1 parameter1, Type2 parameter2, Type3 parameter3)
        { 
        }

    }
```

Type1, Type2, Type3 are other classes. I am creating new object of type Role

```
Role role1 = new Role(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
```

And Adding it to a list

```
 List<Role> listRoles = new List<Role>();
 listRoles.Add(role1);
```

Now I need to fill an excel file with the items of this list, but how I can take the data from my objects in the list.

For an example, the first cell must be filled with **role1.Type1.Name**, how I can access the value of the properties in the object

Comment: Do you know how to use properties with backing fields?

Comment: please dont add a `Closed` tag to your question title when your question has been answered. SO has its own built in way of showing that a question has an accepted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate the list and get the needed values. in this example I'm storing the values in strings, but you can do whatever is needed (e.g. directly write them into the Excel sheet):

```
foreach(Role role in listRoles)
{
    string col1 = role.Type1.Name;
    string col2 = role.Type2.Name;
    // and so on
}
```

I assume, that your `Role` class looks something like this:

```
class Role
{
    public Type1 Type1 { get; set; }
    public Type2 Type2 { get; set; }
    public Type3 Type3 { get; set; }

    public Role(Type1 parameter1, Type2 parameter2, Type3 parameter3)
    { 
        this.Type1 = parameter1;
        this.Type2 = parameter2;
        this.Type3 = parameter3;
    }
}
```

Comment: shame on me, I have forgotten the setter. Thanks for the answer, Romano

Comment: You don't need setter if you are setting properties only in constructor .. after all that's how readonly properties are made.

Comment: @kuskmen I didn't know that. Very nice!